# Export ATT result after psmatch2 command

Tags: stata, propensity-score-matching

I need to export the output from the `psmatch2` *community-contributed* command in Stata.

For example:

```
 psmatch2 treatment var1, neighbor(1) out(depvar)
```

where `treatment` is a dummy variable, `var1` is the regressor used to estimate the treatment probability (pscore) and `depvar` is the outcome variable of interest. The matching algorithm is a nearest neighbor matching.

Output:

[image]

I tried to export the results with the *community-contributed* command `esttab`:

```
 esttab , cells(b se t)
```

However, instead of the ATT, I get the difference between treated and controls before matching:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
use http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/mmabook/nswpsid.dta, clear

psmatch2 TREAT AGE, neighbor(1) out(RE78)

matrix A = ( r(att) \ r(seatt) )

esttab matrix(A)

-------------------------
                        A
                       c1
-------------------------
r1              -20276.95
r2               3224.725
-------------------------
```